# Updating MySQL DB by "rolling up" similar items

Tags: mysql

Not sure if such functionality exists but I'm curious if I have the following DB as shown below, if it can be updated such that wherever **first_name** and **last_name** match all **deduction** and **pay** columns are added together, and thus a single line formed.  I know a query can be written to get me such information, but I need this query result to actually become the database. (i.e. cleaning superfluous extra lines sort to speak).

i.e.

```
first_name | last_name | deduction | pay
skywalker  | luke      | 100       | 200 
vader      | darth     |  50       | 100 
skywalker  | luke      | 400       | 500
```

becomes

```
first_name | last_name | deduction | pay
skywalker  | luke      | 500       | 700 
vader      | darth     |  50       | 100
```

Thanks for the help/advice!

Comment: I don't know if i understand. Are you looking for a view?

Comment: No, it needs to revise the table itself.  So after the "update" is performed, the result is committed to the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer 1

**Create a trigger and another table**

You could create a table called star_wars and another called star_wars_roll_up. Then a trigger on star_wars that aggregate data to star_wars_roll_up. You write to star_wars and read from star_wars_roll_up. It is safe to delete anything from star_wars whenever you feel like it.

```
create table star_wars (name varchar(100), deduction int, pay int);
create table star_wars_roll_up (name varchar(100), deduction int, pay int, primary key (name));
delimiter //
create trigger roll_up before insert on star_wars for each row begin insert into star_wars_roll_up values (new.name, new.deduction, new.pay) on duplicate key update deduction = deduction + new.deduction, pay = pay + new.pay;
end //
delimiter ;

insert into star_wars values ('luke', 100, 100);
insert into star_wars values ('luke', 100, 100);
insert into star_wars values ('luke', 100, 100);
select * from star_wars; select * from star_wars_roll_up;
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer 2.

You could do the view and then periodically drop the extra data (like every night)

```
create table star_wars_new as select * from star_wars_view;
drop table star_wars;
rename table star_wars_new to star_wars;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to do this once, you can just do

```
CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT …;
```

where the `SELECT` pulls the new data you want for the table. Then just rename to replace the table.

```
RENAME TABLE current_table TO old_table, new_table TO current_table;
```